# Sending worklight client logs to server

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

We are using worklight 6.0 version. We are using an adapter to accept logs from device and to store in server. The log level is info. But we are getting debug logs with previous timestamps now. What could be the possible reason for this?

Comment: Where are you storing the logs in the server?

Comment: Sorry, not properly read the question. We are storing logs in .log files

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about the statement regarding timestamps, but if you're getting debug logs in the server that would mean to me that you are not actually sending logs in the correct level. See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.monitor.doc/monitor/c_op_analytics_data_capture.html

If you want to send INFO level logs, set WL.Logger.config({level: "INFO"});

Likewise in the server, set INFO for the following logging options: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.doc/ae/rwlp_logging.html (whichever one you need):

- com.ibm.ws.logging
  .console.log.level
- com.ibm.ws.logging
  .message.file.name